# Vim: Delete Buffer When Quitting Split Window

Tags: vim, git-diff

I have this very useful function in my .vimrc:

```
function! MyGitDiff()
  !git cat-file blob HEAD:% > temp/compare.tmp
  diffthis
  belowright vertical new
  edit temp/compare.tmp
  diffthis
endfunction
```

What it does is basically opening the file I am currently working on from repository in a vertical split window, then compare with it. This is very handy, as I can easily compare changes to the original file.

However, there is a problem. After finishing the compare, I remove the split window by typing :q. This however doesn't remove the buffer from the buffer list and I can still see the compare.tmp file in the buffer list. This is annoying because whenever I make new compare, I get this message:

Warning: File "temp/compare.tmp" has changed since editing started.

Is there anyway to delete the file from buffers as well as closing the vertical split window?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need the `bwipe` command?

```
:bw[ipeout][!] N1 N2 ...
            Like |:bdelete|, but really delete the buffer.  Everything
            related to the buffer is lost.  All marks in this buffer
            become invalid, option settings are lost, etc.  Don't use this
            unless you know what you are doing.
```

One option would be to define the following:

```
function! DelBuf(filename)
     let bname = bufname(filename)
     if l:bname != ""
         let bidx = buffer_number(l:bname)
         exec = "bw " . l:bidx
     endif
endfunction
```

and add a call to `DelBuf("comapre.tmp")` at the beginning of your function.

In theory it should be possible to bind `DelBuf` to the `` `bufhidden `` event like this:

```
autocmd! bufhidden "compare.tmp" call DelTmp("compare.tmp")
```

... but for some reason it didn't work for me.

Comment: OK, thank you for this comment, it is helpful, but it is not what I am asking for. See, the problem is that the buffers seem to be separated from the windows. So when you quit a window, you don't remove the buffer it was editing. I am wondering whether this is possible.

Comment: You need to use vim ``autocmd`` with the event BufHidden to automatically run the ``:bw`` command. This event is triggered when the buffer is no longer visible (i.e., all windows related to this buffer are closed).

Answer (score 1):

I usually define the following things for [diff-buffers](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/diffsaved.vim?r=320):

```
  setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro
  nnoremap <buffer> q :bw<cr>
```

The first line is what will make the difference in your case (`:h 'bh'` -> no need for a single execution autcocommand), the second line is just a shortcut.

BTW: use `r! git` instead of producing a temporary file. This way, you won't have to clear that file either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use autocmd winleave bd (buffer delete). Be warned that if you have the buffer open in more than one window they will all be removed.